# Postback disables javascript when ajaxEnabled set to true

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-mobile, postback

i have a simple form i'm trying to submit, and when i do none of the javascript i have on the page is working (not even alert).

I've found out that if i set jQuery's mobile ajaxEnabled to false, everything works, but how could i get it to work without disabling it?

Now i've tried moving the javascript to the end of the body and that didn't help. So i took a wild guess and thought this could be related somehow that i'm binding my code to the `pageinit` event.

But even alert outside that wrapper didn't work. 
I'm using jQuery mobile so this could somehow be related, or the fact that my page as `EnableEventValidation="False"`

Here's a fiddle for more code : http://jsfiddle.net/DUbXV/

Here's my javascript function declarations (long code) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert();
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
        //using cookie plugin
        $('#user_id').val($.cookie('SimMobileUsername'));

        $('#form1').on("submit", function () {
         //some code
        });
        $("#phone_number").bind("blur", function (event, ui) {
        //some code
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the postback code, if it helps :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        SubmitForm();
}
```

Any thoughts why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

When even alerts aren't working, there's a good chance you have a JS syntax error somewhere.  Have you pulled up your JS or developer console (F12 in most browsers)?  Do you see any JS errors?

If that doesn't resolve, can you post a more complete example here or on jsfiddle?

Comment: ofcourse i've checked syntax errors. this should be a comment not an answer. i don't think you can jsfiddle .net code but i'll add the postback code.

Comment: 'Of Course' - I've heard that many times, do you have Client ID set to static? Otherwise the ASP.NET Items will have different ID's to the ones used in the JS. Also have you got a scriptmanager?

Comment: No most of my elements are regular HTML not asp.net elements. And no i don't have scripmanager. should i? i'm relativley new to asp.net

Comment: I know you can't post .NET to jsfiddle, but can you post a more complete resulting document so we can see what's going on?  If you can't get it to alert anything, it still seems like some kind of syntax error in the resulting document, but as you say it's not, it'd be helpful to have a little bit more information.

Comment: So you're right -- no syntax eror reported in the console.  BUT there is still a blocking/halting error: alert(); I  just assumed that was pseudo code.  But having that, without any parameters, halts execution.  http://jsfiddle.net/DUbXV/1/  Here you'll see just adding an empty string param allows everything to wire up.

Comment: No i tried that too in my case, i edited the question i have more info now.